# Auto_html says block not supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embed, soundcloud

I have a website that allows users to post links. I am trying to get the soundcloud links to embed the mediafile thus I am attempting to use AutoHtml Gem. I did gem install Autohtml, put it in my gemfile and in config/application.rb and ran bundle install. Why isn't Auto_html() working.

```
GEMFILE

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.4'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'rails_autolink', '~> 1.0.9'
gem 'rinku', '~> 1.5.0', :require => 'rails_rinku'
gem 'auto_html', '1.6.0'


CONFIG/APPLICATION.RB

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails_autolink"
require "rails_rinku"
require "auto_html"


VIEW/MICROPOSTS/_MICROPOST.HTML.ERB

<% if micropost.url.include? 'soundcloud' %>
  <%= auto_html(micropost.url)  %>
<% end %>
```

Sorry for the ignorance I'm new to Ror I appreciate the help. I only want to Auto_html here for soundcloud in particular. What am I forgetting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is helper method, so you'll need the following lines:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper
  include AutoHtml
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base # or something like that
  helper ApplicationHelper
end
```

**Edit** if you read the page, there's an example block given: https://github.com/dejan/auto_html

`auto_html(str) { simple_format; link(:target => 'blank')`

For soundcloud use

`auto_html(str) { soundcloud }`

Comment: I needed to put auto_html(micropost.url) {soundcloud}

Comment: +1 Thanks for this! Is there a way to add multiple filters including Soundcloud? The solution only allows for one filter. For some reason simply adding soundcloud to the model doesn't work. Soundcloud only works with your solution but then it can't be combined with other filters. I created another question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831490/auto-html-says-block-not-supplied